# File upload through Nginx with proxy_pass to Gunicorn is slow (Ubuntu 14)

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, gunicorn

I previously was running Ubuntu 12 where I had Nginx receive large file uploads, and then proxy_pass it to gunicorn / django (port 8000). This worked fine once I figured out I needed to set client_max_body_size 300M;. This environment was created using vagrant and chef.

However, once upgrading to Ubuntu 14, I am finding that uploads are extremely slow. Files of 10M take minutes (3% of the file are uploaded every 10 seconds). I looked into increasing proxy pass buffers and other client buffers sizes, but to no avail.

Are there changes to the base parameters from U12 to U14 that may be causing this issue?